# Size of .skp gets doubled after importing to Unity

Tags: unity, 3d-modeling

I have created a 3D model in SketchUp, and it is about 1.6Mb in size. After importing it to Unity, the size more than doubled to 4Mb.

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unity is converting the file from .skp to its own internal binary format, which is less compressed because it is ready for runtime usage.